# Embedded Document & Is there a way to use "type" keyword as a model field name

Tags: sails.js, waterline

This question is seeing a little bit nonsensical. But if there is a way, that'd be great for field name standardization.

- May I use "type" keyword as a field name?

I've changed field name to "method" (another choice is "kind"). But It could have been a sub-document field of Address. For instance:

```
address: { 
     type: { 
              type: 'string'
           }
         }
```

My model as follows;

```
payment: {
    type: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    tally_system: {
        installment_count: {
            type: 'integer'
        }
    },
    gift_card: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    total_amount: {
        type: 'integer'
    },
    discount_ratio: {
        type: 'integer'
    },
    total_amount_after_discount: {
        type: 'float'
    }
}
```

### Edit

I can query an embedded document in Sails as follows. I think, highly probable I can insert an embedded document manually without Waterline and with painful. 
Hopefully newly, Waterline is provided embedded use.

```
Bid.native(function(err, collection) {     
  collection
  .find({'_id' : req.param('id') })
  .nextObject(function (err, bid) {                        
     console.log(bid);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails doesn't support schemas for embedded documents, so you can't do things like:

```
tally_system: {
    installment_count: {
        type: 'integer'
    }
}
```

and expect them to work the way you want.  The best you can do is:

```
tally_system: {
    type: "json"
}
```

which will declare it to be a "json" field which you can put arbitrary Javascript objects into:

```
MyModel.create({ tally_system: [1,2,{abc:123}] })
```

That being said, you can have a field named "type" without it being a problem.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I've added some word to my question the above. Because of I can't write codes here (as comment) properly. Many people try to discover and use in their project MongoDB. And your project very beautiful. I'm just try to use embedded document. Maybe this is a dangerous adventure because of it being possibility of waste time. Thank you again..

Comment: You can use embedded document data in Sails. You just can't declare an embedded schema for your models. Mongodb is a schemaless database after all!